# spring controller doesn't find templates in controller test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I am using spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-test and spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates (1.2.0.M1).

I am trying to build a small application with spring boot. I wrote tests for the mvc controller with mockito. if i run these tests with maven i get the following errors for each controller test:

```
Servlet Could not resolve view with name 'persons/list'
```

I'm not sure if i have configured something wrong.

the errors in the test cases disappear:

- if i change the version to 1.1.7.RELEASE of the spring-boot-starter-parent
- if i make use of component scan and initalize the service bean as a full bean

I have setup a sample project on which the same errors occur like in my app:
https://github.com/waldemar-schneider/spring-boot-mvc-test

what am i missing? thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a reproducible test case, file a bug against Spring Boot on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't enabled auto-configuration in the configuration that's used by `PersonControllerTest` which means that Spring Boot's auto-configuration of its Groovy template support doesn't happen. To fix the problem add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to `ControllerTestConfig`.

It wasn't really working with 1.1.7.RELEASE either, but it was failing in a different way which your tests didn't identify.

If you update your test to also call `MockMvcResultHandlers.print()`:

```java
mockMvc.perform(get("/persons/"));
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("persons/list"))
    .andExpect(model().attribute("persons", hasSize(1)));
```

You'll see in the output that the response has an empty body:

```
…
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 200
   Error message = null
         Headers = {Content-Type=[text/html;charset=UTF-8]}
    Content type = text/html;charset=UTF-8
            Body = 
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

If you add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` as described above, the response will contain the expected HTML:

```
…
MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 200
   Error message = null
         Headers = {Content-Type=[text/html;charset=UTF-8]}
    Content type = text/html;charset=UTF-8
            Body = <!DOCTYPE html><html class='no-js' lang='en'><head></head><body><h2>Person list</h2><table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr></thead><tr><td/><td/></tr></table></body></html>
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

Comment: Thankts for the hint. i didn't see that.
However i don't want to use @EnableAutoConfiguration because i don't want to intialize the whole jpa stack just for the unit tests for the mvc controller. I looked through the initialisation from the groovy markup template view resolver and found a working solution. i imported two config classes from spring boot. you can see the result in the github repository if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `application.properties` is empty
2. What represent `'persons/list'`? a *jsp* file? a *tiles* view name? you need configure `application.properties`
3. Consider something like this

[image: application.properties]

Comment: The application.properties file is only relevant if you use @EnableAutoConfiguration. As i mentioned in the other comment, i don't want to initalize the whole jpa stack (and other features) just to run my unit tests for the mvc controller. I think i described my problem in the question not in all details, sorry for that. but thanks for your thoughts

Comment: I understand, but just curious what is the problem if you add `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, once you have all the Testing in green, you need work in production..Am I correct?